# Redirect Error to log error into a table is not executing

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis

I am trying to load 200000 rows into a table. However, after inserting 1,29,024 rows. the SSIS package is failing with the following error:

Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'X' to data type int.".

There are 40 columns. The package fails every time at 1,29,024. I tried to log record with the problematic data into a separate table, however, the log component is not executing.

What I am doing wrong here? How could be the possible reasons why the error log component is not executing even though the OLE DB Source is failing?

Softwares:
Visual Studio 2013 Professional
SQL server Data Tools 12.0.3
SQL Server 2014[image]

Comment: If this is only for troubleshooting, and the source is SQL Server 2012 or later, you can find the problematic rows using TRY_CAST to integer and then look for NULLs where the original value is not null. As per the SSIS problem itself, are you sure you set all of the properties of the OLE DB source correctly? I especially mean the Error output settings.

Comment: did you change your source error output to "Redirect Row" on failure or is it still set as "Fail component"?

Comment: ThanksPacoDePaco and Tim Mylott,I figured it out. The issue was in a Date column (which was being calculated from different NVARCHAR columns each for DAY, MONTH, YEAR and TIME from the OLTP) in a sub-query deep inside the main query.